# Why does GetCurrentDirectory break up?

Tags: c++

I tried to get the current directory using `GetCurrentDirectory()` but it returns the dir till there is a a space ' ' on the dir like if the current dir is

```
C:\Users\Mix Prog\prog1\Debug
```

then it return only till

```
C:\Users\Mix
```

Can someone point out why it happens like that?
Here is my code:

```
TCHAR priv[BUFSIZE];
DWORD dwRet;    
dwRet = GetCurrentDirectory(BUFSIZE, priv);

TCHAR command[BUFSIZE] = L"cmd.exe /C ";
wcscat_s(command, priv);
```

Comment: What `dwRet`'s value is?

Comment: Either `BUFSIZE` is too small, or (most probably) you are using `priv` in a wrong way. Let's see the whole code.

Comment: The command you are building is not going to work, since you are not quoting the path.

Comment: `command` must be large enough and, as pointed by Matteo, if you're not quoting a path that includes spaces you will end with just a part of it.

Comment: How did you debug priv value? Did you look in debugger or use printf or message box? because if you pass this path to cmd you need to add " before and after path: "cmd.exe /C \"C:\Users\Mix Prog\prog1\Debug\""

Comment: @ZDF I didn't get you quite well.

Comment: You are right: I was not clear enough. `cmd` will interpret the path as separate strings if you do not enclose it in `"`. For instance `command "c:\program files"` is correct. `command c:\program files`, is not. Also, the correct version of `strcat` is `_tcscat_s`. If you are using MFC, I would suggest you to use `CString`.

Comment: @ZDF it works quite well if i move the app to a dir something like C:/users/prog.exe but if it some in a dir with space it fails. any idea?

Comment: I will try to explain you in other words. If you open a console and you're trying to run the same command; does it work?

Comment: "returns the dir till there is a a space". How do you know? Have you printed `priv`?

Comment: Yes, without seeing what you're actually **doing** with `command`, speculation is pointless. The need to quote paths containing spaces is a basic feature of `cmd` and most other shells, not a C++ problem.

Comment: @ZDF yes but a dir exactly without no space.

Comment: @n.m. Becuase does do the function what exactly i said to.

Comment: @underscore_d Iam trying to open the file from current directory whenever the application is placed.

Comment: I'll say it yet again: Have you tried adding quotes around the result of `GetCurrentDirectory` before concatenating it into your command.

Comment: @Polaq So, do you understand now why it does not work?

Comment: @underscore_d As well as ZDF Yea, Thanks much. yeah it works after i did it but including a line of code, I commented a code to remove the file instantly after createprocess handle. is there anyway to solve it by removing the file as well after it is completed successfully.

Comment: "does do the function what exactly i said to" What could this possibly mean? Let me ask the important question again. **Have you printed `priv`?** If yes, what output did you see? If not, **how do you know what was in `priv`?**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that (instead of using wscat_s) you change your code to something like this:

```
wsprintf (command, "cmd.exe /C \"%s\"", priv);
```

As others have pointed out, I suspect priv is correct in your code (i.e. if you look with a debugger the contents are correct), but cmd has not interpreted it correctly because of the space.

Answer (score -1):

In windows API we can get directory from below code

```
 // Get Current Dir  
 #define BUFSIZE MAX_PATH             
 TCHAR myDir[BUFSIZE];
 DWORD dwRet;    
 dwRet = GetCurrentDirectory(BUFSIZE, myDir);
```

Comment: The whole `#define BUFSIZE` is completely pointless. If you're going to use `MAX_PATH`, then use it. Otherwise, avoid macros like the Zika virus. Use a `const` value.

Comment: ...what? You're just repeating the OP's code back to them with 1 word changed and a comment and pointless macro added. (I mean really, the Windows API is ugly enough already without adding your own, and totally pointless, macros to it.)